# Proving an inequality involving integer polynomial

Tags: polynomials, inequality

So we've got an integer polynomial $P$, and all we know about it is that $P(1) = 1$, $P(2) = 2$, and also $P(100) = -k$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z},\, k \geqslant 0$ - some unknown constant, which will never be found. How can one show that $P(100) < -1000$?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it as follows. Using the Euclidean algorithm for polynomials, write $P(x)$ as $(x-1)(x-2)(x-100)Q(x)+R(x)$, where $R(x)$ is quadratic. Show that $Q(x)$ and $R(x)$ are integral polynomials, and also $P(1)=R(1)$, $P(2)=R(2)$, $P(100)=R(100)$. So we reduced the problem to quadratic polynomials, and surely it is easy finish from here.

Comment: Alternatively, $P(x)=(100-x)Q(x)+P(100)$, $P(100)\equiv1\bmod{99}$, $P(100)\equiv2\bmod{98}$, and apply the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: The choice $P(x)=x-(x-1)(x-2)=-x^2+4x-2$ has $P(1)=1,P(2)=2,P(100)=-9602$.  Gerry shows that this is the largest possible negative value since, given only $P(1)=1$ and $P(2)=2,$ either $P(100) \ge 100$ or $P(100) \le -9602.$

Comment: @GerryMyerson The initial solution seems a little rough to me, yours it truly elegant. I wish I could give you "the best answer"… if there is a way, please tell.

Comment: Since you posted to MO, a "site for professional mathematicians", @GHfromMO assumed you could handle the case of quadratic polynomials, Maria. There's nothing "rough" about that solution, it just requires some work on your part to flesh it out. I'm glad you found my approach "elegant". I'm not fussed about who gets "best answer".

Comment: @GerryMyerson The case of quadratic polynomials is indeed no problem, but I faced some difficulties proving that $Q(x)$ and $P(x)$ are integer polynomials, and you can blame me for spending several hours trying to figure that out – all in vain. I'm not even sure it's needed in case of $Q(z)$. Excuse me my complementing your solution and not the original one.

Comment: If by "integer polynomial" you mean "polynomial with integer coefficients", Maria, then you're just dividing an integer polynomial $P$ by a monic polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)(x-100)$, and polynomial long division gives you an integer polynomial quotient $Q$ and an integer polynomial remainder $R$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My bad, now I see. Thanks a lot!